# How to read/get TimePicker Value with AM/PM?

Tags: java, android

[image]

Here i want to get **2:58 PB when i click on OK**.

My Code

```
 time = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    btnResult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    hours = time.getCurrentHour();
    min = time.getCurrentMinute();
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Here,**getCurrentHour() and getCurrentMinute are deprecated
and getInstance() is allowing only for the API 24 and above.. not below version API**.
Can you pls provide some solutions...thanks

Answer (score 2):

hours will be returned in 24 hours format only..

getInstance will work even before api 24. You can use below code with some changes

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss") ;
simpleDateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
```

If you need to get the time, you need to use getTimePicker Dialog, and get time from onTimeSet Listener

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html

You can use below code - it may not be indented properly but you can generated well formatted code within your android studio,

```
TimePickerDialog  timePickerDialog = new    TimePickerDialog(getApplicationContext(), new     TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
  @Override public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int _hours, int     _minutes) { 
// **utilize __hours and __minutes here after user click ok in the dialog** 
  }
 }, **default_hour, default_minutes, true**
 }

  timePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: that's fine...how do we get it without using getCurrentHour() and getCurrentMinute() method..since it is deprecated.@Girish

Comment: I have to get time from TimePicker not from the system@Girish

Answer (score 1):

Vikash you can try to this code hope this can help you ..

```
   String timeSet = "";
    if (hours > 12) {
        hours -= 12;
        timeSet = "PM";
    } else if (hours == 0) {
        hours += 12;
        timeSet = "AM";
    } else if (hours == 12)
        timeSet = "PM";
    else
        timeSet = "AM";


    String minutes = "";
    if (mins < 10)
        minutes = "0" + mins;
    else
        minutes = String.valueOf(mins);

    String aTime = new StringBuilder().append(hours).append(':').append(minutes).append(" ").append(timeSet).toString();
```

Comment: Thanks @Dileep Patel

Comment: Can you tell me what  should i do for API 19.It is coming like up/down list not Circle.@Dileep Patel

Comment: Vikash Kumar it is by default functionality dependent on Device API level ....and please accept my answer..